# Easiest way to implement an array of oval buttons with links

Tags: 2007

I am trying to implement a SharePoint site with an array of oval buttons (grey with black text) each of which which clicked on should open a website (buttons connect to a web link).

I am trying to do this in SharePoint 2007. Will appreciate if you can tell me an easy way to do this, if possible with complete working code that I can cut and paste to work.

I am thinking that this would be some kind of code I paste in the "Source Editor" part of "Content Editor Web Part".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Content Editor Web Part and format the text using the editing tools. You can do formatted text, tables, hyperlinks, and images etc.

More details: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/content-editor-web-part-HA010024046.aspx#BM3